# Is not saying good morning and jumping straight to instructions considered normal in Poland?

Tags: poland, culture

I am living with some Polish roommates (not actually in Poland but Indonesia) and recently I went to bed ill. In the morning I ran into one, he knew I was sick and he did not ask anything to inform how I was or even say good morning but immediately reminded me of a household chore (which btw I always do timely, it's not some built-up annoyance).

This is not the first instance something like this happened. Is this normal behavior for Polish people and should I just grow a thicker skin when living in a house with them, or are they exceptional and can I talk to them about this? I am from The Netherlands, which is hardly considered a country where we have an abundance of social pleasantries, but to me this is still stone-cold.

Comment: One possibility is that they do not feel as comfortable speaking English as yourself, people often come across as impolite or unfriendly in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Living in Poland ~3 months, and I'd say people there are mostly polite... unless you did something perhaps not offensive but unpleasant or unacceptable in any way.

I'd ask him what's the matter. Sometimes we have no idea we did something wrong, but we can speak and solve the issue.

Comment: I'll ask him when he's back, I just didn't want to make a hassle over something that was potentially just normal to them.